# Unable to navigate to local google drive sync files in Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, synchronization, google-drive

I am using linux mint 20.1 Cinnamon. I have turned on google account in *online account* setting for google drive syncronisation.

So in my folder explorer, there is an entry under networks relating to my google account that I signed into. It shows the current state of my google drive.

The problem is that I am not able to use this location in my applications. For example, I am not able to use this location of google drive files in my Obsidian app.

When I print the directory of the google drive folder, it shows as: `/run/user/1000/gvfs/google-drive:host=gmail.com,user=[my_username]`

Now I am unable to navigate to this location as there is no folder `gvfs` inside the folder named `1000`

Is there a workaround? I need to sync files from my google drive into a local copy.

Answer (score 0):

Is your directory 'google-drive' activated via the 'google-drive-ocamlfuse'  program (https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse)  ?